# Weird properties with mouse events

Tags: python, windows, electron, mouseevent, taskmanager

```python
from pynput.mouse import Listener

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        print(f"Click detected")

def run_listener():
    with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
        listener.join()

run_listener()
```

I have a simple python program that captures clicks on the screen, while running it I opened the task manager and noticed that the clicks are simply not detected when the mouse is on top of the task manager, this property made me question what happens and how happens, I didn't find anything about why this happens, I wanted to replicate this operation in an electron app for example for security reasons but apparently this is more difficult than it seems. Perhaps there is some way to block global mouse events (coming from the system) within electron, or something similar.

I researched a little about it and came across that windows does this to ensure security and make malicious apps know patterns of click movements to do something bad or anything like that. Even knowing that, I can't say that it's really because of that and even then I can't replicate this property.

Answer (score 0):

In Electron, you can stop mouse detection (in the browser, not the system) with the following:

```js
win.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true)
```

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window

...but the interception from Task Manager you describe is very likely coming from a Windows hook.

> A hook is a mechanism by which an application can intercept events,
> such as messages, mouse actions, and keystrokes. A function that
> intercepts a particular type of event is known as a hook procedure. A
> hook procedure can act on each event it receives, and then modify or
> discard the event.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-hooks

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, this changes the mouse event property on the electron window, this means that if there is a button inside that window it cannot be clicked, in the task manager there are clickable "items" that despite being able to be clicked don't log any activities within the console which is exactly what I need.