# Ignoring clicks coming from the system

Tags: python, windows, electron, mouseevent, hook

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener
import tkinter as tk
import threading

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    root.update_idletasks()
    if pressed and not (0 < x < root.winfo_width() and 0 < y < root.winfo_height()):
        print(f"Click detected")

def start_listener():
    listener = Listener(on_click=on_click)
    listener.start()

def run_gui():
    global root
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("500x500")
    root.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: True)

    listener_thread = threading.Thread(target=start_listener)
    listener_thread.start()

    root.mainloop()

    listener_thread.join()

run_gui()
```

This question is part of a set, [Weird properties with mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76148143/weird-properties-with-mouse-events), this is the main link, the above code detects clicks on the system and makes a window where these clicks they are purposely not detected, a padding inside that window because I didn't configure this problem very well, so ignore this fact, my problem itself is that I want to do this using electron instead of python's tkinker, despite the two not having relations either it is possible to see a certain similarity in what they offer. Summary: Do exactly what python code does only in electron.

Remember that solutions like win.setIgnoreMouseEvents(true) don't work because it ignores mouse movements on the electron and not on the system, so if there is a button inside the electron window it cannot be clicked. Summary two: Items inside the electron can be clicked on but the system itself cannot detect this itself exactly like in the python code I showed.